# Bootstrap Columns equal height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT3AE.png)

Hi all, I've a little issue.

I'm currently working on a project, with a custom lay-out. The image is a part of the lay-out where i find my problem.

I need to make a part of the website, with products on the left, middle and right. Currently, i've coded like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 offset-lg-1 col-lg-3 product-left">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 product-middle">
      <div class="card pm-first"></div>
      <div class="card pm-second"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 product-right">
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just can't figure out how to make sure, the 2 products in the middle will always  have a equal height of the ones one the left and the right.

I hope someone can help me out, i just don't see it at the moment, sorry for this rookie question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Add `"row-flex row-flex-wrap"` class to your row

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
        <div class="col-12 offset-lg-1 col-lg-3 product-left">
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 product-middle">
            <div class="card pm-first"></div>
            <div class="card pm-second"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3 product-right">
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS File

```
.row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.row-flex-wrap {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex: 0;
}
.row-flex > div[class*='col-'], .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
    margin: -.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
}
.container-flex > div[class*='col-'] div, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] div {
    width:100%;
}
.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1 100%;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.flex-grow {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for helping out! 

It's almost how i want it, the two in the middle just have to get under each other, offcourse with some margin in between :-)

Comment: Can you try another row between two columns.And add row-flex row-flex-wrap class for that. I am not sure it will work or not please check. If it is correct please accept my answer